# CW Complex of an n-torus?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

As part of an exercise out of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology I want to compute the homology of an n-torus by cellular homology, where we've defined the torus to be the square $X = [-1,1]^n$ with pairs of opposite faces $X \cap {x_i = +-1}$ for $ i = 1, 2, ... ,n$ identified by reflection in the plane ${x_i = 0}$.

I can "see" that one CW structure of the n-torus is binomial, $ \binom{n}{k}$ for the number of k-cells etc. And I've drawn appropriate diagrams for the 1, 2, and 3-tori to show this. But I'm not sure how to prove it for the other naturals. Can anyone offer a hint or some guidance?

Comment: So you have two matrices, of size ${n\choose k-1}\times {n\choose k}$ and ${n\choose k}\times {n\choose k+1}$. Are you able to sort the cells in such a way that the matrices have a nice understandable shape?

Comment: Wait can you step back a bit, where are you pulling the idea of having these matrices from?

Comment: Homology is about the kernel of a linear map quotiented by the range of another linear map, right?

Comment: Got it brill, think I've worked it out !